# locating element using c++ functions

Tags: c++

I have a mesh with whole info including nodes, edges and faces in 2D. The mesh has been translated from Gmsh into C++ code. I also have some points in the same 2D space.
I'm looking for the best possible algorithm (fast with low memory cost) to locate elements which my points belong to. I can simply loop over particles and calculate the coordinate, but regarding memory (for big mesh) it is not efficient.

can any one help me through this!?

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail the best I can do is suggest you read up on [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). It works like a binary tree for numbers but in 3D (with points).

Comment: thanks, sorry that I can not give more detail, otherwise I have to update the whole code, but what I can say is that, I have a mesh, and I have all vertices in the mesh, and edges and faces, I know each node belongs to what edge or face. I have some points in space as well, I want to find out these points belong to which face. I will read about Octree .